# Sorting using created at and updated at in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

Why do we need created_at or updated_at for sorting since the objectId already contain timestamp.

We can simply do

```
Products.find({"p":p}).sort({'_id': 1}).exec(callback);
```

or

```
Products.find({"user_id":user_id}).sort({'_id': -1}).exec(callback);
```

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `created_at` is `Date` when document has been created, and `updated_at` is `Date` of the latest document update:

If you don't use either of these fields in your application, there are chances you don't need them.

There are few usecases where document's id is not enough:

- filter or group by `created_at`
- filter, group, or sort by `update_at`